# AWS: How to get and use credentials for an IAM Role in NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-sdk

For my **ExpressJS/NodeJS** app server, which uses its **own** AWS account, I need to access resources in a **different** AWS account. I have set up an **IAM Role** that should allow my server to access this other AWS account.

But the AWS documentation on how to get the **credentials** using this IAM Role are a little thin.

It seems like I might want to use **AWS.STS's assumeRole()** to get back the credentials. Is that the best way to get credentials for this Role?

And if I use assumeRole(), then once I receive the credentials in its callback, how do make use of them so that subsequent calls to DynamoDB and S3, for example, will operate on this **different** AWS account? Would I set the credentials into **AWS.config.credentials**, for example?

Suggestions and code examples would be most welcome!

Thanks.
-Allan

Comment: The easiest thing might be to allow an IAM role in the same account as the instance to access the remote services, then assign that local role as the *instance role* for this machine.  The role would be used automatically.

Comment: Are you accessing the AWS API using [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)? Can you not just create a new user on the other AWS account with the limited permissions that your app needs and then use `AWS.config.update()` with the `accessKeyId` and `secretAcccessKey` for this new user?

Comment: JS example of assume role here - https://github.com/stickytickets/node-aws-assume-role/blob/master/lib/assume-role.js